# JavaFX Textfield - Override default behaviour when up key is released

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to set TextField's cursor/caret to be at the end when the up key is released:

```
private void setTextFieldBehaviour() {
    _textField.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent key) {
            switch (key.getCode()) {
                case UP:
                    if (key.isControlDown()) {
                          ... // Do something for Ctrl + UP key
                          break;
                    } else {
                      ... // Do something for plain old UP key
                      _textField.end();
                      // _textField's cursor will go back 
                      // to the front when the UP key is released!
                      break;
                    }
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

However, as stated in the above code's comment, because I am only overriding the method `setOnKeyPressed`, this means that the default behaviour when the keys are released will kick in for JavaFX's TextField,

Consequently, this makes it difficult to set the TextField cursor at the end when the UP key is released.

I thought of overriding `setOnKeyReleased` just for UP (as shown below), but this has the ugly effect of the cursor jumping to the front of the TextField, then jumping back at the end.

```
_textField.setOnKeyReleased(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent key) {
            switch(key.getCode()) {
                case UP:
                    if(!(key.isControlDown())) {
                      ... // Do something for plain old UP key
                      _textField.end();
                      // _textField's cursor will go back 
                      // to the front when the UP key is released
                      // then jump back to the end again!
                      break;
                    }
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
    });
```

Or visually, this is how it appears:

**Before pressing anything: // Cursor is placed at the end of the string**
TextField[oldString |]
**Press UP: // Cursor is in front of string**
TextField[| oldString]
**Release UP: // Cursor is back of string**
TextField[newString |]

So currently, I am able to set it to go to the back, but this entails the cursor jumping around. Is there anyway to do it better?

Comment: you could try  maybe `onKeyTyped`-(the function name might be wrong) ? and push your codes there. but search for a keyevent function the last one they are 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at those sample application that show 2 way to achieve this:

by setting the event Handler and consuming the event.

```
public class main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    HBox root = new HBox();

    TextField textField = new TextField();

    textField.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {

        if (e.getCode().equals(KeyCode.UP)) {
            textField.end();
            e.consume(); // this stop propagating the event
        }

    }); 

    root.getChildren().add(textField);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

or by filtering the event and stop its propagation

```
public class main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    HBox root = new HBox();

    TextField textField = new TextField();

    textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, e -> { //event filter first catch the event

        if(e.getCode().equals(KeyCode.UP)){
            textField.end();
            e.consume(); // this stop propagating the event 
        }
    });


    root.getChildren().add(textField);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 300);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

You should look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/events.htm to learn how event are processed in javaFX.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to go with the `e.consume();` approach and it worked beautifully. And I'll be sure to take a look at the tutorial you've linked.