# JavaFX TextField override key UP/DOWN behaviour

Tags: java, events, javafx, key, textfield

I'm designing a custom time control with a TextField and want to implement the function to increase the hours or minutes when pressing the UP-Key.

This is how i intended to do it:

```
textField.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
    int caretPos = editableNode.getCaretPosition();
    switch (event.getCode()) {
    case ESCAPE:
        getSkinnable().reset();
        event.consume();
    break;
    case UP:
        if (!getSkinnable().isInvalid()){
            if (caretPos < 3) {
                getSkinnable().increaseHour();
                selectHour();
            } else {
                getSkinnable().increaseMinute();
                selectMinute();
            }
        }
        event.consume();
    break;
    }
});
```

The problem here is that the UP-Key on default sets the caret to the beginning of the text.

I already found this post: [JavaFX Textfield - Override default behaviour when up key is released](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36359046/javafx-textfield-override-default-behaviour-when-up-key-is-released)

But the event that sets the caret at the beginning of the text comes before my eventhandler so this did not help me.

Does anyone know how I can "override" this behaviour?

Comment: What about adding a ChangeListener on the field.caretPositionProperty() in order to get the old caret location before the change occurred and then set the caret location to the old value?

Comment: Did you try adding an event filter (instead of `setOnKeyPressed`), and consuming the event?

Answer (score 1):

The solution of @James_D resolved my issue.

```
textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event -> {
    int caretPos = editableNode.getCaretPosition();
    switch (event.getCode()) {
    case ESCAPE:
        getSkinnable().reset();
        event.consume();
    break;
    case UP:
        if (!getSkinnable().isInvalid()){
            if (caretPos < 3) {
                getSkinnable().increaseHour();
                selectHour();
            } else {
                getSkinnable().increaseMinute();
                selectMinute();
            }
        }
        event.consume();
    break;
    }
});
```